# reading variable value declared in script.sh in Makefile

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, global-variables

I run makefile to generate an image file for a target device. After I burn the image into the target device during one of the operation funtion1.sh calls script.sh where my VAR is declared.

I want during running Makefile to generate the target image access script.sh knowing the path, read the value of VAR and use it in Makefile.

example:

script.sh:

...

VAR=some_value

...

=====Now what script do I need for Makefile ???===============

-I tried this method but it did not work--------------------------

Makefile:

`PLAT_SCRIPT := /path/to/script.sh`

`PLAT_VAR := VAR`

`PLAT_SCRIPT_TEXT := $(shell grep ${PLAT_VAR} ${PLAT_SCRIPT}) VAR := $(filter-out ${PLAT_VAR}, $(strip $(subst =, , $(subst ",, $(strip ${PLAT_SCRIPT_TEXT})))))`

`all:`

```
  @echo VAR=$(VAR)
```

It did not work for some reason. Maybe I should replace line 4 with:

`VAR := $(shell echo $(PLAT_SCRIPT_TEXT)|cut -d, -f1|awk -F'=' '{print $2 }' )`

`all:`

```
 @echo VAR=$(VAR)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must export the variable to make it visible in subprocess.

exporting variable from Makefile to bash script:

```
export variable := Stop

all:
    /path/to/script.sh
```

or export it using shell style:

```
all:
    variable=Stop /path/to/script.sh
```

---

exporting variable from shell to make:

```
export variable=Stop
make -C path/to/dir/with/makefile
```

or:

```
variable=Stop make -C path/to/dir/with/makefile
```

or:

```
make -C path/to/dir/with/makefile variable=Stop
```

---

If you need to read variable from script you can find it's declaration and extract the value like that:

script.sh:

```
...
VAR=some_value
...
```

Makefile:

```
VAR := $(shell sed -n '/VAR=/s/^.*=//p' script1.sh)

all:
    @echo VAR=$(VAR)
```

*But, think this is not a very good method.*

---

Better is to output results of execution in the script and fetch it in Makefile.

Example:

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR=some_value

# some work here

echo "some useful output here"

# outputting result with the variable to use it in Makefile
echo "result: $VAR"
```

Makefile:

```
# start script and fetch the value
VAR := $(shell ./script.sh | sed -n '/^result: /s/^.*: //p')

all:
    @echo VAR=$(VAR)
```

Comment: I tried to export variable from Makefile using 

export variable := Stop

all:
    /path/to/script.sh

as well as 

all:
    variable=Stop /path/to/script.sh


and in my script.sh I used 

echo "$variable"

nothing, did I reference the "variable" correctly in script.sh ???

Comment: Maybe you have wrong script or wrong path? try to do it on clean Makefile+script. It works well.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am sure the method you describe it should work. When you run make it will export the variable
and at that process you can access the variable. In my problem, i run makefile to generate an image file. After I burn the image into the target
i invoke the script.sh file, so in that case the export variable of Makefile is not there anymore.

Comment: In the script.sh file I declare

variable=Stop

In Makefile i do this:

#Specify the path to the platform script which contains the variable
PLAT_SCRIPT := /path/to/script.sh

Comment: #Parse the platform script to get the variable line
PLAT_VAR := variable
PLAT_SCRIPT_TEXT := $(shell grep ${PLAT_VAR} ${PLAT_SCRIPT})

Comment: #extract the variable from the  string 
variable := $(filter-out ${PLAT_VAR}, $(strip $(subst =, , $(subst ",, $(strip ${PLAT_SCRIPT_TEXT})))))


However, It still does not work!

Comment: Don't understand where you exporting variable and where you trying it to use. Something like that? 1) Makefile(1) -> Call Makefile(2) to burn image. 2) Makefile(2) Burn image and export variable, exit to 1. 3) Makefile(1) start script.sh? If yes, there is no method to modify parent environment. You must pipe result or store it in temp file.

Comment: yes, I think you are correct. Now, when I run Makefile(1), instead of export, i need to go and read from script.sh file the variable since it is there, i know the path and it is declared in script.sh.

Comment: Basically, read the script.sh file, find the line which start varialbe, using grep function. Then I need to strip the variable and extract the value of variable, maybe I can use,

Comment: variable=`echo $PLAT_SCRIPT_TEXT|cut -d, -f1|awk -F'=' '{ print $2 }'`

Comment: Thanks. It worked I used 1st method because second method will not work for me as I cannot invoke script.sh before doing Makefile. Makefile procedure is done on a PC, then image is burned in the target device. That target device will not run again Makefile, but later it will invoke script.sh through different function.sh.

Comment: Therefore I used your 1st method it worked. The only thing I tweaked  is 

VAR := $(shell sed -n '/product_name=/s/^.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/p' script1.sh), since in I declared VAR = some_value in my script.sh file. This is to assign some_value, instaed of "some_value"

Comment: In most cases quoted "some_value" is suitable and you don't need to strip quotes. If my answer solves your question, please mark it a solved.

Comment: did I make it correctly? i raised the number on the left and mark the green OK sign?

Comment: You are right in most cases I do not need to strip the quotes. But your answer solved my question thanks again.